# Does a matrix with negative eigenvalues have singular values?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, definition, singular-values

What if the eigenvalues of a matrix $A$ are all negative? Does that simply mean there is no singular value for this particular matrix?

I can't calculate the conditional number or matrix $2$-norm for this matrix. Please clarify.

Comment: Recall the definition of singular value and answer your own question.

Comment: Why would you think that there are no singular values?

Comment: because singular values are meant to be nonnegative, and from my notes, i don't seem to see to take the square root of the absolute value of the eigenvalues as the singular values.

Comment: "Take the square root of the absolute value of the eigenvalues as the singular values" of what matrix? Look closely.

Comment: symmetric matrix?

Comment: By definition, the singular values of a matrix $A$ are the eigenvalues of $A^*A$ (eventually excluding the null eigenvalues).

Comment: in this case, would it be true that for any symmetric matrix A, its singular values are simply the absolute value of its eigenvalues?

Comment: @Laurykninu Yes, this is true for every complex normal matrix (including real symmetric ones).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to compute singular values for a matrix $\mathbf{A}$. Start with a product matrix, either $\mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A}$ or $\mathbf{A}\, \mathbf{A}^{*}$. Typically, you pick the smaller of the two.

1. Compute the eigenvalue spectrum for your choice of product matrix. For demonstration, we choose
   $$
    \lambda \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} \right).
   $$
2. Remove the zero values. A matrix of rank $\rho$ will have $\rho$ eigenvalues greater than $0$.
3. Order the eigenvalues such that

$$
  \lambda_{1} \ge \lambda_{2} \ge \dots \ge \lambda_{\rho} > 0.
$$

4. The singular values are now
   $$ 
     \sigma_{k} = \sqrt{\lambda_{k}}, \qquad k=1, 2, \dots , \rho
   $$

The matrix condition number is
$$ 
 \kappa_{2} \left( \mathbf{A} \right) = \frac{\sigma_{1}}{\sigma_{\rho}}.
$$

Comment: I think you forgot the square roots in part 4.